# How can I include a DropDownList in a menu bar using the Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, menubar

Assuming programming in C++ for the Win32 API, I would know if it is possible to include a DropDownList (COMBOBOX window with CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style) in a menu bar.

Any light in that matter or where start to learn on the topic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owner drawing is your only option for customizing the built-in API menus. Not only is that a giant pain in the rear, it still won't produce the effect that you want. You'd have to draw the combo box by hand and write code to respond to all the mouse events, instead of just dropping in a standard combo box control.

**My suggestion is to use either a toolbar or a [rebar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774373.aspx) that simulates a menu bar**, rather than the standard menu bar. This is what Windows (and Internet) Explorer does to draw its menu bar, and it provides you with a lot more flexibility in what controls can be included.

- There's a complete description of how you might do this using a toolbar available here:
  [Creating an Internet Explorer-style Menu Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775450.aspx)

  [image: Internet Explorer-style menu bar]
- And you can find sample code for the rebar here: [Using Rebar Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774536.aspx)

  [image: Sample rebar control with a combo box]

Comment: Cody Gray: thanks for your suggestion. I feel that in this case, your advice about the Rebar Control is the "silver bullet". I will try it in the next few days and hope not need to ask again about the matter. By the way, I hope found some plain C/C++ examples in the M$ site althought in this last times, I feel a bit disoriented because all seem about .NET C# and all that "new" gadgets.

Comment: @Old newbie: Yeah, I think a rebar is definitely the nicest solution available here. And as far as MSDN, I agree. Although I don't think they've *removed* anything, they've just tried to do a better job documenting the new .NET stuff. Which is commendable, I suppose, but less than helpful unless you know exactly what you're searching for. You should be able to find some more samples online now that you know a rebar is the way you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to handle all paint messages you can ultimately do anything to the client area of your application. How much work and code are you prepared to put in?

Comment: Boofhead: Regarding the work, spare no one, but I would not disproportionately increase the size of the executable for the sole purpose of including a cosmetic improvement -the combobox can also be the client area of the main window-.

My first idea was to include the classic style, but I have the problem of how obtain the "handle" of the menu bar for do the test. It would also have to make a "subclassing" on the control.